# Websphere : Automatically Clean temp folders while startup

Tags: caching, websphere, temp

How to make Websphere to automatically clean up temp folders during wach start or restart ?

I found out how to manually delete them. But can't ask the customer to do it. Is there some parameter or something that can be set in order to delete the cache/temp files automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You weren't specific about what cache or temporary files you wanted to delete, but in general, there is no WAS setting to do so.  The logging system can be configured to roll log files over, but those aren't temporary files and typically you would want to keep them for some period of time for audit purposes.   You also typically don't want to delete caches like the OSGi class cache, unless specifically told to do so by IBM support, so I would't suggest doing it on a server start/restart.  The configuration repository uses temporary files that could be deleted on server start/restart. see [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tcfg_console_tempfiles.html) for details on the location of the files.  Having said all that, if you're sure you know what files to delete, I'd suggest wrapping calls to the startServer or stopServer files with your own script(s).  These are either batch files on windows platforms, or shell files on other platforms and shouldn't be modified by users.  In your wrapper, simply delete the files and then call startServer.

Comment: I need to delete the temp folder which is here :  WAS_HOME\AppServer\profiles\<profile_name>\temp